# What is the idiomatic way to build to/move compiled Cljs to an arbitrary directory when using Boot?

Tags: firefox-addon-sdk, clojurescript, boot-clj

I'm using ClojureScript, Boot and Boot-Cljs to build a Firefox Add-On. Firefox's Add-On SDK assumes a certain directory structure; in my case, I'll need a `project-root/data` directory, which will house my `contentScriptFile`.

How should I go about building a ClojureScript file, which lives in `project-root/src/foo/core.cljs` and either outputting it or moving it to `project-root/data`? I've tried using `boot sift --move` to no avail (I admittedly don't fully understand how this task is supposed to work, which arguments are required, etc.), using a `main.cljs.edn` manifest and tweaking its location, `:asset-path`, `:output-path`, etc. to no avail.

```
;; src/main.cljs.edn
{:require [foo.core]
 :init-fns [foo.core/init!]
 :compiler-options {:output-path "data"}}

;; build.boot
(set-env!
  :source-paths #{"src" "data"}
  :dependencies '[[org.clojure/clojure "1.7.0"]
                  [org.clojure/clojurescript "1.7.170"]
                  [adzerk/boot-cljs "1.7.170-3"]])

(require '[adzerk.boot-cljs :refer [cljs]])

(deftask build []
  (comp (cljs :optimizations :whitespace)))
```

I'm intrigued by Boot and want to figure this out, but I have to admit, I've wasted *a lot* of time on this ([and it looks like I'm not alone](https://github.com/adzerk-oss/boot-cljs/issues/104)). Seeing as I already have a simple, working Clojure script which calls the ClojureScript compiler directly - and uses `:output-to` to do exactly what I need - I may revert back to that approach in order to wrap this experiment up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The weird thing about Boot that looks to be tripping you up a bit is that tasks - such as the `cljs` task - don't necessarily interact directly with the filesystem.  They interact with the [FileSet](https://github.com/boot-clj/boot/wiki/Filesets#the-boot-fileset), a type of immutable value they are passed and expected to return.

At the beginning of the build, Boot gathers files on disk into the build's first FileSet.  Then, it threads the FileSet through the task stack.  Finally, Boot writes the FileSet returned by the last task to the [target directory](https://github.com/boot-clj/boot/wiki/Target-Directory).

Boot's `sift` task can be used to move files around *within the FileSet, returning a new FileSet*, but not to move files outside of the target directory.

Long story short, I think you can do what you want by specifying a target directory to Boot like so:

`(set-env! :target-path "data" ...)`

Comment: Thanks, Alan! I'll give this a try shortly.

Answer (score 2):

This task might help:

```
(deftask public []
  (comp (production)
        (build)
        (sift :invert true :include #{#"js/app.out" #"js/app.cljs.edn"})
        (target :dir #{"data"})))
```